# Controlling rounding with floating values

Tags: boost, floating-point, bigint

I am using large integers (128 bit or more) with boost. I want to avoid some very slow divisions by using floating point. I can get away with just the upper bits of the quotients in many cases and I want to use this by using floating point.
Say I have:

```
ccp_int a, b; // big integers +ve
double fa, fb; // a float that would be big enough to hold the exponent.
fa/fb >= a/b  so a floor of a divide
(fa - 1) / fb + 1 <= (a - 1) / b + 1  a ceiling of a divide
```

So presumably this means being able to assign fa = a say with correct rounding and also to do the divides rounding in different directions.
Is this the kind of thing you can control with floating point? My experience of fp is pretty much zero.

Comment: I managed to find fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD) etc to control assignment it seems.

Comment: In C++? Typical C++ implementations do not have great support for full IEEE-754 semantics, and changing the rounding mode may be a costly operation. You could set it to truncate (round toward zero) and leave it that way for your work, but it could affect other things in your application.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I coded a bit of it up (yes c++ on windows) and see that it makes calls to change the rounding. I will look for faster interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Eric mentioned, [fesetround()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround) is in principle the way to control the float rounding mode, but unfortunately it does not have great support.

Here is a thought on a way around this. Extract the upper 32 bits manually, then use POD arithmetic to compute the division. So essentially, emulate the floating point conversion and division in order to have full control over how rounding is done. To simplify this outline, I'll assume `a` and `b` are both positive at least 2^32, and hopefully it will be clear how to fill these details for a general implementation:

1. Use `a_bits = msb(a)` to get the index of the most significant bit in `a` that is set to 1 (for more details, search for "msb" in [this page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/number.html) on boost number).
2. Get the upper 32 bits with `uint32_t a_high = a >> (a_bits - 31)`.

   This step is effectively a rounding operation, rounding down. To round up instead, we can increment `a_high` by one if `lsb(a) < a_bits - 31`, that is, if the lowest set bit occurs below the extracted 32-bit portion. (An edge case is that this increment may cause the uint32_t to overflow, which I'll ignore.) I'll use "`a_high_down`" to refer to rounding down and "`a_high_up`" for rounding up.

   Either way, we have a float approximation of the dividend `a`:

   ```txt
   a ≈ 2^(a_bits − 31) ⋅ a_high.
   ```
3. In the same way, make an approximate representation of the divisor `b`:

   ```txt
   b ≈ 2^(b_bits − 31) ⋅ b_high.
   ```

Then, the division `a/b` is approximately

```txt
a/b ≈ 2^(a_bits − b_bits − 32) ⋅ (2^32 ⋅ a_high) // b_high,
```

where `//` denotes integer division rounding down. The numerator `2^32 ⋅ a_high` should be formed by casting `a_high` to uint64_t and shifting up.

A couple notes:

- This adjustment is important so that the quotient keeps some bits of precision (since `a_high` and `b_high` have similar magnitude, doing simply `a_high // b_high` as an integer division would give only 1 bit of precision).
- Instead of this 32-bit shifting, we could have extracted `a_high` as the upper *64 bits* of `a` for a little more precision.

To bound the quotient from above and below, compute

```txt
a/b ≤ 2^(a_bits − b_bits − 32) ⋅ ((2^32 ⋅ a_high_up − 1) // b_high_down + 1),
a/b ≥ 2^(a_bits − b_bits − 32) ⋅ (2^32 ⋅ a_high_down) // b_high_up,
```

where `//` denotes integer division rounding down. The divisions on the rhs can be done in native uint64_t arithmetic. Finally, cast these division results to cpp_int and left-shifted by `(a_bits − b_bits − 32)`.

### Examples

**Ex 1.** For the values

```txt
a = 2^100 ⋅ 123456 = 156499072501776288991176990922899456,
b = 2^70 ⋅ 123455 = 145749938535668012464209920,
```

the exact quotient is about a/b = 1073750521.434887. The procedure above accurately approximates this, with the first 10 digits correct:

```txt
a_bits = floor(log2(a)) = 116
a_high = a >> (116 − 31) = 4045406208

b_bits = floor(log2(b)) = 86
b_high = b >> (86 − 31) = 4045373440

a/b ≈ 2^(a_bits − b_bits − 32) ⋅ (2^32 ⋅ a_high) // b_high
    = 2^(−2) ⋅ (2^32 ⋅ 4045406208) // 4045373440
    = 0.25 ⋅ 4295002085
    = 1073750521.25.
```

**Ex 2.** For the values

```txt
a = 10^50 = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
b = 9^50 = 515377520732011331036461129765621272702107522001,
```

the exact quotient is about a/b = 194.03252175, and

```txt
a_bits = floor(log2(a)) = 166
a_high_down = a >> (166 − 31) = 2295887403
a_high_up = a_high_down + 1 = 2295887404

b_bits = floor(log2(b)) = 158
b_high_down = b >> (158 − 31) = 3029116820
b_high_up = b_high_down + 1 = 3029116821

a/b ≤ 2^(a_bits − b_bits − 32) ⋅ ((2^32 ⋅ a_high_up − 1) // b_high_down + 1)
    = 2^(−24) ⋅ (9860761315478339583 // 3029116820 + 1)
    = 2^(−24) ⋅ 3255325530
    = 194.03252184

a/b ≥ 2^(a_bits − b_bits − 32) ⋅ (2^32 ⋅ a_high_down) // b_high_up
    = 2^(−24) ⋅ (9860761311183372288 // 3029116821)
    = 2^(−24) ⋅ 3255325526
    = 194.03252161
```

Comment: I don't think this works if a_high and b_high are near the same size. The division will not generate many significant bits. So a = 123456*2^100, b = 123455*2^70 should give a/b close to 1073750521. Scaling will give us (123456*2^47)/(123455*2^47) giving only 1 bit of precision. Maybe I made a mistake here? Floating values do the correct thing here as they generate values below the decimal.

Comment: You are right, I forgot an important step: `a_high` needs to be shifted up before the division, otherwise all precision is lost. I revised my answer above to take this into account and added a couple examples.

Comment: Thanks Pascal I will give this a try. I coded up the floating point version and this does perform well.